# nmap url with ip scaning issue?

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

nmap gives error while scanning a URL with IP:

```
nmap http:\\X.X.X.X\sample
```

**Message**

```
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.24 seconds

Unable to split netmask from target expression:..
```

is there a specific syntax for this ?

Answer (score 3):

nmap scans IP addresses. It does not scan URLs. You can run:

```
nmap X.X.X.X
```

instead, where X.X.X.X is the IP address (or domain name).

Besides that, http:\\X.X.X.X\sample is not a URL, because it has backslashes instead of forward slashes.